# Applying reactive technique to external system interfacing with Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am quite thrilled with reactive programming RxJava after reading about it and checking some tutorials online. I want to apply it in my project.

My project (say X) interfaces with external system in a way that some request is sent to system **Y** through JMS and until response is received (in configurable duration) process halts. Now, traditionally we have a time monitor system that  keep polling in fixed intervals to check if response arrived and if it doesn't it informs X and X takes some action. But in the same time Y can send back response and X has to take care of it too.

There is race condition involved here and also lot of concurrency issue because it involves CRUD transactions lots of book keeping and updates on object involved.

Enter RxJava this fits my use case perfectly by applying Observables (between X and Y) and Observers (X) clearly but I wish I could also leverage some timer or monitoring behavior so that X don't wait for response from Y forever but get notified that response is delayed and you no longer need to wait for it, plus do some book keeping about delayed response etc.

Does RxJava provides some mechanism to clock the request and response duration ? 
Do you think RxJava fits my UC or you have some better suggestion.

My main concern is to handle concurrency because this system suffers a lot of issues while handling responses in parallel and updating objects. While RxJava sounds promising because it will reduce concurrency by allowing sequence of events (response when arrives), is that wrong assumption ?

Note : This is not a mobile application we are talking here.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, RxJava is a very good fit for what you want to do here. `Observable.timeout` will emit an error if no items are emitted within a time span. (This propagates downstream as an error and upstream as an unsubscription, so you can perform proper processing at the source).